# Duckduckgo Android search Intent

Tags: java, android, duckduckgo

Anyone knows the intent to search directly through the official Duckduckgo app on Android?

> Tried this one so far, i think they dont have a `query` key in `extras`

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
    intent.setPackage("com.duckduckgo.mobile.android");
    intent.putExtra("query", subject);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: found their github [link](https://github.com/duckduckgo) it would be a pain to tinker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is actually pretty simple than i thought

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://duckduckgo.com/?q=" + subject));

    try {
        intent.setPackage("com.duckduckgo.mobile.android");
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        intent.setPackage(null);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```